# How can I center the text I just changed?

Tags: python, wxpython

There is a static text in the center, which by clicking on the button changes to a random text from file.

And here's the problem itself: after pressing the button, the new text starts from the beginning of the previous peace text, not in the center.

How can the problem be solved?

```
import wx
import random

class TestWindow(wx.Frame):

    def chBtnClick(self, event):
        f = open("Words.txt", "r")
        random_word = random.choice(f.read().split("\n"))
        self.chText.SetLabel(random_word)
        
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(300, 200))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        VSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.chText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Click Random")
        VSizer.Add(self.chText, 0, wx.CENTER | wx.ALL, 5)
        
        self.chBtn = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, label="Random!")
        VSizer.Add(self.chBtn, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.chBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.chBtnClick)

        self.panel.SetSizer(VSizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestWindow(None, "ExBurate Test ver.")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Before button

[image: Images before buttom]

After button

[image: and after]

Comment: You should either close the file `f` or use the `with` construct i.e. `with open("Words.txt", "r") as f:` which will close the file automatically.

Comment: Well, so far everything works.
What you wrote is likely more related to optimizations. But I still haven't figured out how to write the code for this.

Comment: True! As you already had an accepted answer, I simply thought that I would add, that every time you click that button, you are opening a file and `not` closing it. I could have noted that you could load the file contents once, also an optimisation. Just trying to be helpful, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks! But how to say - my program has grown, and it uses a lot of actions on the file (i,e "r", "a", "x"), to do all this with one activation, I can't imagine. I can also drop the link to my project, just need testers :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After change the text call `self.panel.Layout()` to re-center object

```
def chBtnClick(self, event):
    f = open("Words.txt", "r")
    random_word = random.choice(f.read().split("\n"))
    self.chText.SetLabel(random_word)
    self.panel.Layout()
```